# How to full screen in selenium (ChromeDriver)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get my test window to go full screen but all the commands I have tried have failed. This include trying to enter ASCII keyboard codes and also I've had a look through all the selenium commands and found nothing relevant but cant seem to make the browser go to full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it hasn't been implemented in the ChromeDriver yet.  Here's a link to the issue.

http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=67